# Compressing CSS from LESS

Tags: css, less

So I have a long stylesheet that I use for a subreddit on Reddit and to make it easier to edit, it's in a custom version of LESS. Essentially I add a bit, put it through a JS script (with Node), which converts it to LESS, then converts it to CSS. But it spits out at least 8 lines more than it should.

LESS:

```
.flair {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -999em;
    font-size: 0;
    background-image: url(%%SPRITE%%) !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.flairthree {
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    &::before,&::after {
        .flair;
        content: "";
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
    &::before { left: -31px; }
    &::after  { right: -31px; top: -30px; }
}

.flair.flair-blackwidow     {   background-position: 0  -120px; }
.flair.flair-captainamerica {   background-position: 0  -210px; }
.flair.flair-ironman        {   background-position: 0  -660px; }

.flair.flair-basic {
    .flairthree;
    .flair.flair-captainamerica;
    &::before { .flair.flair-ironman; }
    &::after  { .flair.flair-blackwidow; }
}
```

Which then spits out:

```
.flair.flair-basic {
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background-position: -0 -210px;
}

.flair.flair-basic::before,
.flair.flair-basic::after {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -999em;
    font-size: 0;
    background-image: url(%%SPRITE%%) !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.flair.flair-basic::before {
    left: -31px;
}
.flair.flair-basic::after {
    right: -31px;
    top: -30px;
}
.flair.flair-basic::before {
    background-position: 0 -660px;
}
.flair.flair-basic::after {
    background-position: 0 -120px;
}
```

As you can see, the CSS has two additional selectors each for `::before` and `::after`. Is there anyway I can write the LESS styles differently to get the same results minus the 8 lines? I would write some more JavaScript but it would be too complicated and difficult.

Comment: Can you try http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Less leaves this kind of optimization to a dedicated tools/libs. For instance [`--clean-css="advanced"` option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#v2-upgrade-guide-clean-css) will optimize these redudant rulesets for you.

Comment: @seven-phases-max And how do you do that in NodeJS? I looked through and I can't figure out how to add these flags.

Comment: [Using a Plugin in Code](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code). Though if you writing your own script it's easier to use [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css (or any of tens of similar libs) directly.